Let's merge 'blockchain-wallet-app' into 'blockchain.info'
We have a tag called blockchain-wallet-app. It deals with substantially the same issues as the blockchain.info, and is used interchangeably.
Examples:

I have Blockchain.info wallet which i can't find
how to do address callbacks?

We should also remove it from questions in some cases:

How does the network apply credit for created blocks?


I would think the blockchain-wallet-app would apply to a subset of all blockchain.info questions. There isn't currently a blockchain.info API tag, so maybe we could make one.

@StephenM347 Yeah, it seems like most people who want to ask about blockchain.info's API just combine the blockchain.info and API tags. :/
